# Delay execution of SQL script in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Does Redshift have any functions similar to `pg_sleep()` in PostgreSQL?

I have a SQL script that needs to wait for some time before continuing with the execution.

The [Unsupported PostgreSQL Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) Redshift documentation that says `pg_sleep()` is not supported.

Update 1:

I am running into deadlock issue in Redshift. I have multiple processes that can query a table (or set of tables) with `DROP/TRUNCATE/INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT`. If there is a deadlock, I was trying to catch this exception and have the process wait for sometime and retry. Are there any recommendations on ways to handle deadlocks?

Comment: Does it just need to wait for a certain duration, or does it need to wait until some external event has (hopefully) happened?

Comment: Yeah, are you worried about eventual consistency or some similar case?

Comment: Forcing your script to wait is almost always the wrong thing to do - what is your use case i.e. why do you want to sleep?

Answer (score 13):

A sketchy not recommended approach is to use a Python [User Defined Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION janky_sleep (x float) RETURNS bool IMMUTABLE as $$
    from time import sleep
    sleep(x)
    return True
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

select janky_sleep(5.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using lock on the table. I have had a similar situation like you, lock on the table helped me over come that.

Comment: How did you create that lock?